# ¿Cómo muestro el libro mas caro de cada categoría?

Tags: mysql

He probado con

```
SELECT nombre, categoria_id , precio FROM libro WHERE precio=(SELECT MAX(precio) FROM libro);
```

Pero solo me aparece el libro mas caro

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Podrías leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Te falto el `GROUP BY categoria_id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo sin usar subqueries utilizando [Window Function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html) desde MySql 8.0:

```
SELECT DISTINCT categoria_id,
       FIRST_VALUE(nombre) OVER (PARTITION BY categoria_id ORDER BY precio DESC) AS nombre,
       FIRST_VALUE(precio) OVER (PARTITION BY categoria_id ORDER BY precio DESC) AS precio
FROM libro 
ORDER BY categoria_id;
```

Si quieres utilizar una subquery sería así:

```
SELECT *
FROM libro
WHERE (categoria_id, precio) IN (SELECT categoria_id, MAX(precio)
                                 FROM libro
                                 GROUP BY categoria_id);
```

También puedes hacer un JOIN con la subquery que tiene los precios máximos por categoría:

```
SELECT l.*
FROM libro l
INNER JOIN (SELECT categoria_id, MAX(precio) AS precioMax
           FROM libro
           GROUP BY categoria_id) AS s ON l.categoria_id = s.categoria_id AND l.precio = s.precioMax;
```

Comment: Muy util! Nunca habia escuchado de Window Function. Podrias poner desde que version esta disponible?

Comment: Hola, gracias! Windows Function en MySql existen a partir de la versión 8.0. Son muy utiles.  [En este enlace podes probar mis queries con datos de ejemplo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8c025c99d68ba89c4eda7a7a2b04286c)

Answer (score 0):

Tines que incluir a tu tabla categoria con un  INNER JOIN o LEFT JOIN en este caso si ya te muestra el libro mas caro deberia ser algo asi :

```
Select p.nombre,c.nombrecategoria,p.precio from libro p left join categoria c on c.idcategoria_id=p.idcategoria_id where p.precio =(select max(p.precio));
```

me comentas como te va.